# View and partition in PieCloudDB database

Tags: view, database-partitioning

Does PieCloudDB database support partition and view? How to partition a table by time or enumerated values?

Comment: Have you try the examples below in your PieCloudDB？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples of partitioned tables and views in PieCloudDB database are as follows:

1.Create partitioned table.

```
create table test_partition_list(
  member_id numeric,
  city character varying(32)
)
partition by list(city)
(
  partition guangzhou values('guangzhou'),
  partition hangzhou values('hangzhou'),
  default partition other_city
);
```

2.Views

```
create table lineitem ( l_orderkey    integer not null,
                        l_partkey     integer not null,
                        l_suppkey     integer not null,
                        l_linenumber  integer not null,
                        l_quantity    decimal(15,2) not null,
                        l_extendedprice  decimal(15,2) not null,
                        l_discount    decimal(15,2) not null,
                        l_tax         decimal(15,2) not null,
                        l_returnflag  char(1) not null,
                        l_linestatus  char(1) not null,
                        l_shipdate    date not null,
                        l_commitdate  date not null,
                        l_receiptdate date not null,
                        l_shipinstruct char(25) not null,
                        l_shipmode     char(10) not null,
                        l_comment      varchar(44) not null);
```

```
create view vw_lineitem as 
  select l_orderkey,l_quantity,l_discount,l_tax from lineitem 
  where l_orderkey in (select l_orderkey from lineitem where l_linestatus='0');
```